# Can I create a trigger on insert that will generate a random number for a key in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table definition:

```
        CREATE TABLE Content (
            [ContentId] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
            [Title] NVARCHAR (50) Not NULL,
            CONSTRAINT [PK_Content] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ContentId] ASC)
        )";
```

Instead of an identity column I need to generate a random 5 digit number for the ContentId and for this number to have **not been previously used**.

Is there a way I can do this with some kind of database trigger for an insert in SQL Server 2012 ?

Comment: Why you don't want to use identity?

Comment: Actually it's not my choice. I do want to use identity but I was told to look into ways it could be coded with a random key.

Comment: Does it have to be 5 digit number? Or just any random key?

Comment: The random 5-digit number is max 100000 entity. Is that enough? In this case, I suggest to use [uniqueidentifier](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx) data type for primary key.

Comment: What would be the benefit of a random PK over identity? From the client-side perspective, both are server-generated, meaningless numbers, one being foreseeable, the while the other isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only dealing with 100,000 values.  My suggestion is to create a lookup table for mapping an auto-incremented id to a new id.  Here is the code for creating such a table:

```
with nums as (
      select 0 as n
      union all
      select n + 1
      from nums
      where n < 9
     ),
     nums5 as (
      select n1.n*10000+n2.n*1000+n3.n*100+n4.n+10+n5.n as val
      from nums n1 cross join nums n2 cross join nums n3 cross join
           nums n4 cross join nums n5
    )
select val,
       row_number() over (order by newid()) as new_content_id
into LookupTable
from nums5;
```

With this table, put an auto-incremented id in the table and then lookup the five character "new_content_id" from this table.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a good starting point to do what you want :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/61cc6/20)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Content (
            [ContentId] INT NOT NULL,
            [Title] NVARCHAR (50) Not NULL,
            CONSTRAINT [PK_Content] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ContentId] ASC)
        );
```

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @key VARCHAR(5), @i int
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(120)
SET @i = 1
WHILE @i > 0
BEGIN
    SET @key = (SELECT ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % 89999) + 10000)
    SET @i = (SELECT count(*) FROM Content WHERE ContentId = @key)
END
SET @query = 'INSERT INTO Content (ContentId,Title) VALUES ('+@key+',''Whatever'+@key+''');'
exec(@query)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/61cc6/20/0)**:

**Query 2**:

```
DECLARE @key VARCHAR(5), @i int
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(120)
SET @i = 1
WHILE @i > 0
BEGIN
    SET @key = (SELECT ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % 89999) + 10000)
    SET @i = (SELECT count(*) FROM Content WHERE ContentId = @key)
END
SET @query = 'INSERT INTO Content (ContentId,Title) VALUES ('+@key+',''Whatever'+@key+''');'
exec(@query)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/61cc6/20/1)**:

**Query 3**:

```
select * from Content
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/61cc6/20/2)**:

```
| CONTENTID |         TITLE |
|-----------|---------------|
|     22537 | Whatever22537 |
|     66089 | Whatever66089 |
```